# ipython notebook editor missing functionality, for instance header cells

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Apologies for the ridiculously simple question, but google is not revealing the answer.

I am new to iPython notebook, and recently created my first one.  For some reason, my notebook editor does not look like editor in the tutorials online, and has less functionality.  I would like to make heading cells in my notebook, but I don't seem to have the option to make headings and the keyboard shortcuts for headings don't work either.  For instance, ctrl-m c and ctrl-m m work as expected to toggle between code and markdown formats, but ctrl-m 5 just types a 5.

[image: Here] is a screenshot of what the editor looks like on my computer

[Here is one example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/table_of_contents_ipython.ipynb) of online screenshots that show an editor that looks different from mine.

Can you help me figure out how to make header cells/restore any other missing functionality to my notebook editor?

Thanks!

Comment: On the left bar, you have Cell. In that you have Markdown. You can use it to create various sizes of fonts/headings. Learn a bit about markdown.

Comment: @ChillarAnand I suppose you didn't understand my question.  I understand that markdown can change the size of text. There is a specific type of cell in iPython Notebook called a heading cell that was not available to me, even though it should have been, and in general my notebook looked different from examples.  I wound up getting the answer to my question on the ipython-user list.  If anyone else has this problem, see here: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Re-can-t-RESOLVED-make-header-cell-in-ipython-notebook-editor-editor-in-general-seems-different-froms-td5070162.html

Comment: Is this question still active? It look like you have an outdated version of IPython.

Comment: I did, and I I figured it out.  Thanks very much.